# What conventions are used with accidentals and tied notes?

Tags: notation, accidentals

If I have a tied note across a bar line, say 2 whole G notes, and I have an accidental, say a sharp, on the first G, my assumption is that the accidental applies as well to the second G because it is tied. If I wanted it to not apply, what would be the convention?  Would it be simply to not have a tie note in the first place and have two separate notes, a sharped G and a G itself?

Comment: If the second note is not augmented, then you can't have a tie at all, since it doesn't connect equal pitches. (However, if you use a *slur* for phrasing or legato, which looks similar and can be confused with a tie, then you should definitely include a complementary cancellation sign.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An accidental does apply across the bar line, but would need to be reapplied to any applicable notes *after* the second note under the tie. Ties don't apply to different notes. (You'd use a slur instead if you wanted the 1st note held until the 2nd note is attacked.)

If, say, you sharp a G and tie it across the bar line, then follow the second note under the tie with G♮, you *may* want to use a cautionary accidental to show that the sharp has come off. If the sharp wasn't part of the key signature, this isn't absolutely necessary, but it usually saves a bit of confusion.

The following example should make this clear.

[image]

Comment: Great answer! I would always use a cautionary accidental. If I saw that measure without it, I would almost surely play G# again.

Comment: Well, yeah, @NickB. The rule says that the accidental only applies in the bar in which it is added, but, in cases like this, it can look a lot like a proofreading error if the cautionary isn't there.

Comment: Could you expand on the the engraving difference between a tie and a slur? I saw in your example that they don't look the same, but I had never noticed. Very interesting!

Comment: @Gauthier, my notation software is a bit old, or the differences would be even more obvious. Ties tend to be more "in between" the note heads than slurs, usually with less curvature: they rarely extend more than 1 to 1-1/2 lines or spaces in depth past the line or space the note is occupying. When flipped (because the note is in the upper voice of a multi-voice stave), they remain between the note heads. Slurs will migrate to the ends of the stems in a multi-voice setting.

Comment: Yeah, it can be hard to distinguish between ties and slurs on old sheet music.  Even some new stuff.  I'd probably default to assuming it's a tie if the note doesn't change -- it's on the arranger to make it explicit if not.

Comment: Does it really matter whether you got a tie or a slur though? A slur for two notes that were the same would, if anything, reduce down to a tie (what does two consecutive notes at the same pitch sound like when played in legato mode?); and you can't have a tie between two notes with different pitches. It almost feels easier to think of the slur and tie as the same thing.

Comment: @Speldosa, put more than one voice on the stave. Are ties and slurs the same then?

Comment: @Patrx2 Hmm... I can't think of an example with several voices on the same staff where it would be necessary to make a distinction between the two. Maybe I should turn this into a new question instead of discussing it in the comment field :)

Comment: @Speldosa, might be a good question. I can think of a few instruments where it would be possible to re-attack a note (i.e., distinct attack) without a break - that's makes for a good slur but an incorrect tie. From point of view of _notating_ multi-voice music, though, slurs and ties are placed differently.

Comment: @Patrx2 Good point! I created a question about this: http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/33611/are-there-any-situations-when-one-needs-to-make-a-distinction-between-slurs-and

Comment: @Speldosa, I see that. user21166 has done a good job of amplifying my point here. Main thing is that ties really denote a _single_ note.

Comment: I've more often heard a "cautionary accidental" called a "courtesy accidental" instead.

Answer (score 1):

Tied notes are, by definition, the same note carried across a bar line. When the second note is different, even though it may be the same letter name, but altered with a #, b or natural, then that note will have to be played as a separate note in the new bar. Then, the 'tie' line becomes a slur. Yes, if it's the same note, there's no need to put the # in your case. There would certainly not be a tie - there couldn't be.

This answer is direct to your question, as you stated the second G (G natural)lasted the whole bar, Which takes a different slant from Patrx2's answer, which correctly states what happens to SUBSEQUENT notes of the same name in a second bar.

Comment: I don't understand the part "there would certainly not be a tie." It sounds like you are agreeing with Patrx2's answer, but if it's the same note and there's no need for the #, doesn't that make it in essence a tie of G#'s spanning the two measures?

Comment: If the 1st bar was G#, and the 2nd, G natural, there could be a slur, but not a tie. It's not possible to tie dissimilar notes. This is how I interpreted the question. If the two notes were the same, then yes, they could be tied, and would not need the 2nd accidental, as you said.

Answer (score 1):

Others have already stated that a tied note does not call for a repeat accidental but any following notes will.  This is correct with one exception: if the tie is broken across lines, the tied note after the line break *will* require a repeat accidental which then counts for following notes as well.

This is one of the rare cases where line breaks affect details of notation inside of the lines.

Comment: FWIW, this rule doesn’t seem to be consistent across scores. Looking through my scores from various publishers/editors, I see many follow it (e.g. Urtext, Mandyczewski Brahms, IMC) but some don’t (e.g. Paderewski Chopin). Dorico, usually so scrupulous about these sorts of rules, does not follow this one. I wonder if it’s a regional thing, or just a matter of taste?