# Why include both "sempre legato" and slur marks?

Tags: piano, notation, slurs, legato

In Mendelssohn's *6 Kinderstücke* Op. 72 No. 2 "Andante Sostenuto" (See the first 6 bars in the image below) there is the indication to play "sempre legato" and there are slurs as well.

[image: Mendelssohn op. 72, no. 2, mm. 1–6]

Questions:

1. Where does the "sempre legato" start? From the 3rd bar or from the 2nd?
2. Since the slurs imply: play legato, is this redundant with the "sempre legato"? If not, how should I play the slurs?

The edition I am looking at here is the RCM Level 8 List C - 2015 Piano Celebration Series.

Slurs are present in the score even after the 3rd bar for LH and RH.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Notice that the slurs go away in bar 3. That's the purpose of the *sempre legato*. It's saying "keep playing this as in the first two measures", rather than writing slurs through the entire score.

As the piece progresses, the left-hand is also intended to be *sempre legato*, except in the couple of places where notes are separated by rests.

The remaining slur marks are primarily phrase markings. Rather than indicating articulation, a phrase marking is a guide to shaping the musical interpretation. The Q&A [Understanding and distinguishing piano slurs and phrases](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/52878/70803) discusses the distinctions between slurs and phrase marks.

Comment: Your answer prompted me to look for other editions, in the one shown above there are slurs from bar 4 till the end, both for LH and RH. In another, found on IMSLP, the LH does not have slurs until the last bar.

Comment: @Qvantvm I can't tell if that's a question or a statement. Either way, links or more specific references to the editions you're referring to would be helpful. If there's something more you need from my answer, please let me know.

Comment: I added the edition I was referring to. Based on your answer and what I found on other editions I think the "sempre legato" is referring to the LH only. Unless there is another interpretation.

Comment: @Qvantvm  I think not.  Partly because the LH ISN'T legato.  It's got rests in it!

Comment: @Qvantvm this answer is correct; I recommend accepting it.  This sort of thing is common.  More generally, you might see _simile,_ which means "you get the idea; keep doing it like this even though we're going to stop writing the articulation marks everywhere."  In this case, rather than _simile,_ the editor has chosen a message that is consistent with the meaning of the specific mark being omitted.  In other cases you might see _sempre staccato_ or _sempre marcato,_ for example.  Doing it this way reduces visual clutter.  If the composer's manuscript survives, have a look at that.

Comment: @LaurencePayne but the pedal is engaged continually.  (One wonders, therefore, whether the pedal marking is Mendelssohn's; why expend more time and effort writing short notes and rests when the dampers are off?)

Comment: I notice that [this edition](http://conquest.imslp.info/files/imglnks/usimg/2/24/IMSLP103386-PMLP22724-Mendelssohn_Werke_Breitkopf_Gregg_Serie_11_Band_2_MB_64_Op_72_scan.pdf) shows *sempre legato* in bar 3, with slurs the same.  I agree with your *simile* interpretation.

Comment: @phoog IMSLP says the piece dates to 1842, and their earliest entry is printed by Novello. It (and the next-oldest) say nothing about pedal. That PDF, though, comes [from Sibley Library](https://urresearch.rochester.edu/institutionalPublicationPublicView.action;jsessionid=D0AB4A6C9730D6F52DED82BF8ED11D15?institutionalItemVersionId=23236) who dates it to 1820. Conclusion: The Time Bandits stole the pedal marking!