# Tying accidental natural with same note that has # from key signature

Tags: piano

If I have F#  in key signature and I put natural sign in front of this note and I am tying it across the bar line with same F natural do I have to put natural sign on note across the bar too?

Comment: Incidentally, this is the subject of some [unexpected behaviour](https://youtu.be/msJ6-wawFnc) in Finale notation software.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't need to set the accidental again in the next bar ( if you mean this);
the accidental in front of a tied note is  affecting the tied note in the next bar too, as e.g. 2 half notes tied across the bar line have the same meaning like one whole note. and the 3 most usual accidentals (there are still double sharp and double flat) are all treated the same. You also don't have to put (repeat) the accidental in the next bar in front of the 2nd tied note, but it is always possible to set it again in brackets (#).

I think this question is asked and answered here. 
[What conventions are used with accidentals and tied notes?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/33533/what-conventions-are-used-with-accidentals-and-tied-notes)
the problem is a little bit different but is included if you read this information:
https://datadragon.com/education/reading/symbols.shtml
in the explanation and examples of Wikipedia 
"the sharp (♯), flat (♭), and natural (♮) symbols, among others, mark such notes—and those symbols are also called accidentals",  they didn't show especially the case of the natural one. but they are handled the same way, you may now combine it with the double sharp (x) and double flat (♭♭) too.